# How to connect to Docker daemon if unix:///var/run/docker.sock is not available and docker is running

Tags: linux, docker, apt, snap

I had an issue with docker installed with snap, and I moved to apt. This was on a production server. In order to have a low downtime, I did the following:

1. Removed snap running containers
2. Removed `/snap/bin` from `PATH`
3. Installed docker as recommended [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)
4. Rebuild and start the containers
5. Disable docker from snap with `sudo snap stop docker` and `sudo snap remove docker`

Everything was ok. Next day, I tried to restart the containers used for monitoring, but the following error is raised when running `sudo docker ps -a`:

```bash
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

The daemon is running:

```bash
root       42709  0.2  0.3 2344140 54276 ?       Ssl  Sep07   5:30 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root       42868  0.0  0.0 1813868 5944 ?        Sl   Sep07   0:16 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8072 -container-ip 172.19.0.3 -container-port 8072
```

How can I recover control of the docker daemon?

Comment: `-H fd://` means dockerd's control socket is inherited rather than opened. This happens when docker is handled by a service manager such as systemd using socket activation. So if docker wasn't started by systemd, but something else and systemd isn't actually listening to (/var)/run/docker.sock then chances are nothing is. So you should as root check `fuser /run/docker.sock` and tell if you think your system was tweaked.Anyway I'd rather have installed the distribution's package (on Debian or Ubuntu): docker.io rather than a 3rd party repository even if this 3rd party happens to be upstream.

Comment: `systemctl cat docker.socket` could also help.

Comment: I have tried as root: `fuser /var/run/docker.sock` the result is:
`Specified filename /var/run/docker.sock does not exist.`

Comment: and what was the results of the other commands?

Comment: This is the result for the other command:

# /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
[Unit]

Description=Docker Socket for the API


[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

Comment: As root `lsof -U -a -n -p 42709`: does it still show a line with `/var/run/docker.sock`? If that's the case I'm afraid I don't know how to recover this (the usual trick used to recover content of deleted files still in use doesn't appear to work for unix sockets).

Comment: I have this: `dockerd 42709 root    9u  unix 0xffff933e30218000      0t0 127706147 /run/docker.sock type=STREAM`

Comment: I guess the way packages were installed and uninstalled using two packaging systems possibly running Docker twice at some time made in the end disappear `/run/docker.sock`. You'd have to restart Docker to hopefully recover access. If that's production then there should be preproduction first to reproduce this. If it's desperate then injecting a payload with GDB to do `close(9)` and then recreate a new unix socket at /run/docker.sock and dup2() it to fd 9 could work. But any mistake would crash the process instead.

Comment: I fix the problem by reinstalling docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin

Answer (score 11):

Assume docker engine is installed in a similar way as [offical doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

## The reason

In your running `dockerd`,

```
/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
                 ^^^^^^^
```

(Marker `^^^` is added by me to point to the position within a line, it's not a part of the shell output.)

According to [daemon socket option doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option),
the `-H fd://` means the daemon is using a file descriptor managed by systemctl. There will be no socket file `/var/run/docker.sock` in this case.
But `docker` cli will try to connect to the docker daemon via the `docker.sock` socket file, that's where the problem comes from.

## The solution

In the case I run into, the docker daemon is brought up via systemctl as a service, you can find the service file path using systemctl command, for example, (marker `^^^` is added by me to point to the position within a line, it's not a part of the shell output)

```shell
ubuntu-linux-22-04-desktop:~$ sudo systemctl status docker

● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-05-19 23:59:31 CST; 55s ago
...
```

Then, modify that file on the line how `dockerd` is brought up

```shell
sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

In the opened file, find a line starts with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd`

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
...

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

...
```

Modify the `-H` argument in `dockerd` command to use unix socket rather than `fd`, change the line to

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Save the file (in vim, command model, `zz`), then reload

```shell
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then, restart docker daemon

```shell
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

After docker daemon restart finishes, you should be able to see the socket file

```shell
ll /var/run/*.sock
```

`docker` cli should work now. Try something like

```shell
docker ps
```

Hope will help to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks a ton your answer is the best on web!
according to docs, we can also listen to multiple sockets, which is nice to not break existing sockets
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option